# dart, editor, breakpoints, debug dynamic webpage

Tags: dart

The newest dart editor has support for debugging and breakpoints and it works in a static HTML page. I have an existing backend (Django) and I cannot get the debugger to work when I set the "Launch Target" to a URL.

I get this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching DartEditor".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any ideas?

---

OK, I can use the debugger in Chromium. Apparently, you have to reload the page to see the dart scripts in Chromium.

Comment: Is this still an issue? It seems as though you've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This was like a bug in an old version of the editor. There are [some similar cases](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3510) in the issue tracker marked as fixed. Upgrading to the latest editor will certainly fix it!