# Dart best practices for develop and production

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Sorry if this is a noop question, but I'm pretty new to Dart.
I wonder if someone has good links or ideas for best practices for develop and debug a Dart application in a node.js environment. I can start a standalone Dart app and call a rest api using absolute url, but I think the Dart app should be served using node.js and the urls should be relative.  In production we also need to serve the js compiled app. Do you know how to build a good development environment, near to production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a launch configuration in DartEditor to be able to use the debugger with another web server. 
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3748 (sorry couldn't find a better ressource)

The Dartium built in debugger (Chrome developer tools) works pretty well too with Dart.

You will loose some features like transformers as `pub serve` uses it though.

I guess the best for development is to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your node.js server and develop with the web server built in in DartEditor ([dart: debugging client/server communication for dart client and existing rest api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588864)).
For testing and bug-fixing in an environment similar to the deployment environment use the configuration described above.
Dart is just like static files for the server. You don't loose much when you don't use node.js for serving Dart.